Does the Apéry-like sequence $A_n=(n!)^2\sum_{k=0}^n { \rho \choose k}^2 { \rho+n-k \choose n-k}, \rho=e^{2 \pi i/3}$ change signs infinitely often?
This is an integer sequence OEIS sequence A217703.
It satisfies an order 3 recurrence which is the constant term $A_n=u_n(0)$ of a three term recurrent sequence of polynomial defined by
$$u_0(x)=1,u_1(x)=x, u_{n+1}(x)=(x+2n(n+1))u_n(x)-n^4u_{n-1}(x).$$
It was conjectured that $A_n<0$ if and only if $2 \le n \le 57$ and $n >2177$ but it
turns positive at $n=81935$ and negative again at $n=3082582$, and it should be the case that it changes signs infinitely often.
The very interesting explicit formula for $A_n=(n!)^2\sum_{k=0}^n { \rho \choose k}^2 { \rho+n-k \choose n-k}, \rho=e^{2 \pi i/3}$  with complex binomial comes from a formula in Z. W. Sun's original posting A sequence of irreducible polynomials
$$u_n(x^2+x+1)= (n!)^2\sum_{k=0}^n { x \choose k}^2 {x+n-k \choose n-k}.$$
However the explicit formula does not seem to be of any help for showing infinitely many sign changes.
Reasons suggesting infinitely many sign changes
It can be shown that a 3-term recurring polynomial sequence
$p_0(x)=b_0, p_1(x)=x+a_0, p_{n+1}(x)=(x+a_n)p_n(x)-b_np_{n-1}(x),$
with all $a_j$ real and $b_j>0$ have only real and distinct roots which strictly interlace, ie. there is exactly one root of $p_n(x)$ strictly between adjacent roots of $p_{n+1}(x)$.
An interesting consequence of such interlacing sequence is that is that the roots are aligned. If we let
$r_{n,1}>,...,>r_{n,n}$
be the roots of $p_n(x)$, then for fixed $k \ge 1$, the $k$th largest root $r_{n,k}$ is strictly increasing and the $k$th smallest root $r_{n,n-k+1}$ is decreasing, so that we must have
$ lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} r_{n,k}=\alpha_k \in (-\infty,\infty],$
$ lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} r_{n,n-k+1}=\beta_k\in [-\infty,\infty) $
It could happen that all the $\alpha_k$ are the same , also for $\beta_k$ as is the case for the classical orthogonal polynomials.
Since $sign(u_n(0))=(-1)^m$, where $m$ is the number of positive roots of $u_n(x)$. We can explain the sign changes by
there is only one positive root for $1<n<58$, $r_{n,2}$ become also positive for $n=58$ and also $r_{n,3}>0$ for $n \ge 2178$, $r_{n,4}>0$ for $n \ge 81935$, $r_{n,5}>0$ for $n \ge 3082582$ etc. There are infinitely many sign changes because all $r_{n,k}$ becomes eventually positive.
It could happen that all $\alpha_k$ are distinct (it seems these are the only two possibilities) as in the special case
$a_n=an,b_n=bn$
for $a>0,b>0$.
In this case all $\beta_k=-\infty$ but $\alpha_k=b/a-a(k-1)$ so there are exactly $\lceil b/a^2 \rceil$ sign changes.

The polynomials $u_n$ are essentially continuous dual Hahn polynomials (with parameters $a=b=c=1/2$). Maybe some general facts about orthogonal polynomials, like interlacing of zeroes, can be useful.

I see that you have updated your question based on my previous comment (which makes that comment look very silly). I believe the property you want follows from the fact that the orthogonality measure of the continuous dual Hahn polynomials is unique (the moment problem is determinate) and supported on the whole real line. For any such polynomials, the zeroes should be dense on the line. I haven't found a good reference for this but it should follow from the fact that, roughly speaking, the orthogonality measure can be recovered from the zeroes using Gauss quadrature.

@Hjalmar Rosengren Can you explain how your observation applied. I am looking at the limits of the roots along fixed $k$. It is a discrete set, it cannot be dense.

I mean that the set of all zeroes of all the polynomials is dense. I wrote more details in an answer.

I see two ways to prove this.
Method 1: Generalities about orthogonal polynomials.
In standard notation, your polynomials are
$$u_n(x)=S_n\left(\frac 34-x;\frac 12,\frac12,\frac 12\right).$$
This is clear by comparing the recurrence relation. If you want to compare the explicit expressions, you need to apply a ${}_3F_2$-transformation. The polynomials $S_n$ are orthogonal on the real line, with weight
$$\frac{|\Gamma(1/2+i x)|^6}{|\Gamma(2ix)|^2}=8\pi^2\frac{x\sinh(\pi x)}{\cosh^2(\pi x)}.$$
The corresponding moment problem is determinate, that is, this weight function is unique.
For quite general systems of orthogonal polynomials, one can in principle obtain a weight function (the weight function in the determinate case) from the zeroes, see e.g. G. Freud, Orthogonal Polynomials, Chapter 2. If $r_{n,k}$ are the zeroes of $p_n$, then one can approximate the orthogonality measure by a quadrature formula
$$\tag{1}\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_{n,k}f(r_{n,k}).$$
Then there is at least a subsequence $n=n_m$ so that this converges to an integral
$$\tag{2}\int f(x)\,d\rho(x)$$
as $m\rightarrow\infty$, and $p_n$ are orthogonal with respect to $d\rho$.
In the case at hand, it follows that the zeroes $(r_{n,k})_{n,k}$ are dense in $\mathbb R$. If there is an interval $I$ without zeroes and we take $f$ as the characteristic function of that interval, then (1) vanishes but (2) doesn't. In particular, the $k$-th largest zero $r_{n,k}\rightarrow\infty$. As you mention, it then follows from interlacing of zeroes that  $u_n(0)$ changes sign infinitely often. To repeat the argument, since $u_n(x)\rightarrow\infty$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$ and has only simple zeroes, the sign of $u_n(0)$ is the parity of the number $m_n$ of positive zeroes. We have seen that $m_n\rightarrow\infty$ and, by interlacing, $m_{n+1}\in\{m_n,m_n+1\}$. So $m_n$ has to change parity infinitely often. Here I ignored the possibilty that $u_n(0)=0$ (I don't know if this can happen). But in that case it follows from interlacing that $m_{n-1}$ and $m_{n+1}$ have distinct parity.
Method 2: Asymptotics
I believe that one can prove an asymptotic formula like
$$u_n(0)\sim C_n\big(\cos(A\log n+B)+\mathcal O(1/n)\big),$$
where $C_n>0$ and $A$, $B$ are some elementary constants. See J. A. Wilson, Asymptotics for the  ${}_4F_3$  polynomials,
J. Approx. Theory 66 (1991),  58-71. The polynomials considered there are more general. This would again show that there are infinitely many sign changes, and that the time between them increases exponentially.

Yes thanks for the detail reply. I am convinced of the $(-1)^nS_n(3/4-x,1/2,1/2,1/2)$ now. But this cannot be applied to the distinct roots $a_n=an,b_n=bn$ case. Since $\alpha_{k-1}<\alpha_k$, an $\epsilon$ left neighbour contains only the $r_{n,k}$ so cannot be dense. The coefficients grows linearly where as those of $S_n$ are quadratic.

Yes, your other example seems to be very different. I am not sure exactly what those polynomials are. The recursion looks a little bit like for Charlier polynomials, which is
$$xp_n=p_{n+1}+(n+a)p_n+nap_{n-1}.$$
Charlier polynomials have their orthogonality measure supported on $\mathbb N$.

If one defines the initial condition $p_0=1,p_1=x-a$, the recurrence $p_{n+1}=(x-n-a)p_n-nap_{n-1}$ indeed defines the Charlier polynomial $p_n=(-1)^n {}_2F_0(-n,-x;;-1/a)$. We then have $\alpha_k=\infty, \beta_k=(k-1)$ independent. If $a<0$ roots are no longer all real but limit still holds for the real roots. The unexpected observation is when $a$ is any complex number, the kth smallest real part of the roots still converge to $k-1$. Maybe this is related to universality of eigenvalues.

Should be "independent of $a$" in the last comment.
